Не появляется вторая кнопка в ряду. Телеграм бот aiogram
Использую aiogram 2.25.1
Все данные выводит верно, но не могу понять как выводить по 2 кнопки в ряду. Выводит только  по одной.
Вот код:
async def reply_items():
    keyboard = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True,row_width=2)
    addresses = get_addresses()
    for address in addresses:
        keyboard.add(KeyboardButton(text=str(address[0])))
    return keyboard


async def reply_items():
    addresses = get_addresses()
    items = []
    for address in addresses:
        items.append(str(address[0]))
    keyboard = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard=items, resize_keyboard=True,row_width=2)
    return keyboard


Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit].
